# extract the starting character of ls -l output for a file in unix

Tags: bash, shell, grep, wildcard

Below is the filename:

`-rwxrwxrwx   1 user1 users        268 Sep 16 18:06 script`

what should be the command to grep the first character here?

based on that i want to conclude whether the item is a file, directory, or softlink.

can we use the wildcard "^" to get this info please?

Comment: ["What is the XY problem?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: The first character of `ls -l` output won't always be `-` for files that are neither directories, FIFOs, symlinks or devices -- this very much depends on your operating system's extensions. POSIX *does* specify that the first character specify "file type", and specifies specific characters for several particular types, but also is explicit that "implementations may add other characters to this list to represent other implementation-defined file types."

Comment: BTW, `^` isn't actually a wildcard -- whereas a wildcard matches any character at all, `^` (in regex) matches zero characters (and only at the front of a string). You could thus use `^.` to match a single character at the front of a string -- in which case `.` is the wildcard in use, and `^` is restricting where it matches -- but there isn't much reason to do so here.

Comment: Right. wrt `^` - s/wildcard/metacharacter/.

Comment: maybe a better name for this post would be "how to determine file type".

Comment: @RedCricket, but for that invalidating part of a preexisting answer (that answering the X as opposed to the Y), I'd be in agreement with you. :)

Comment: what preexisting answer? :)

Answer (score 5):

That's the wrong way to tell if something is a symlink; [you should **never** parse the output of `ls`, which is meant for human consumption only](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead, use `test` primitives:

```
for name in *; do
  if   test -L "$name"; then echo "symlink:           $name"
  elif test -f "$name"; then echo "regular file:      $name"
  elif test -d "$name"; then echo "directory:         $name"
  elif test -b "$name"; then echo "block device:      $name"
  elif test -c "$name"; then echo "character device:  $name"
  elif test -p "$name"; then echo "named pipe (FIFO): $name"
  elif test -S "$name"; then echo "socket:            $name"
  else                       echo "other:             $name"
  fi
done
```

The above could also be written as `[ -L "$name" ]`, `[ -f "$name" ]`, etc; just as there's both a shell builtin command named `test` and an executable named something like `/usr/bin/test`, there's also a shell builtin command named `[`, and an executable like `/usr/bin/[` (which behaves in the exact same way, *except* for requiring that its last argument be `]`).

---

Answering your literal question, vs addressing how best to solve your actual/underlying problem:

Once you have content in a string in shell, you can perform a parameter expansion to get the first character:

```
s=abc # or s=$(...some command here...), or so forth
echo "${s:0:1}" # this returns "a"
```

To get the first character of a stream (such as stdout from a piped command), you can simply use `head -c 1`:

```
echo "abc" | head -c 1 # this also returns "a"; echo can be replaced with any other command
```